# ods output in proc logistic

Tags: sas, logistic-regression, proc, ods

I am running a proc logistic with selection =score , to get the best model based on chi-square value. Here is the code

```
  options symbolgen;
  %let input_var=ABC_DEF_CkkkkkedHojjjjjerRen101 dept_gert  home_value   
  child_household ; 

  ods output bestsubsets=score;
  proc logistic data=trail;
  model response(event='Y')=&input_var
  / selection=score best=1;
  run;
```

The output dataset named score has been generated through ods output. Below is the image of the data set.

[score data set image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/InRde.png)

In the score dataset, in the "variables included in model" column, you can only see a part of variable name "ABC_DEF_CkkkkkedHojjjjjerRen101" and not the entire name. May I know why is this happening and how do I get the entire variable name. Please let me know

Comment: SAS variable names are 32 length maximum. Are you mixing up labels and variable names?

Comment: The length of the above variable name is 31 characters. No I am not mixing variable labels and names

Comment: In the future it helps if you post code we can run. Solution is below.

Answer (score 1):

Add NAMELEN=32 to your proc logistic statement.